# Can I use lambda with monorepo and use the internal packages with pnpm?

Tags: node.js, docker, aws-lambda, monorepo, pnpm

I have a monorepo that looks like so:

```
monorepo
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── apps
│   ├── lambda-app-1
│       ├── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── package-1
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
└── turbo.json
```

lambda-app-1 depends on package-1
And also using `pnpm` I have 3 `node_modules` folders:

1. inside `package-1`
2. inside `lambda-app-1`
3. inside root.

How can I make it work for lambda where AWS expects a final of:

```
index.js
node_modules
package.json
```

I am not sure how can I make the installs into a single `node_modules` folder that will also include the packages, or if there's other method to make use of `packages` from the monorepo? building it using docker.